# Ansible Create Dictionary from PowerShell Stdout_lines in List Format

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible task that gets a list of webapplications from a website on an IIS server. By running PowerShell and registering the output. The PowerShell output is formatted as a list and looks like this:

```
"stdout_lines": [
            "",
            "",
            "path         : /QAWOOD8.3.3.API",
            "PhysicalPath : C:\\Wood\\Vision Government Solutions Inc V8.3.3\\CAMA API",
            "",
            "path         : /QAWOOD8.3.3.AppServerManager",
            "PhysicalPath : C:\\Wood\\Vision Government Solutions Inc V8.3.3\\AppServer Manager",
            "",
            "path         : /QAWOOD8.3.3.DataService",
            "PhysicalPath : C:\\Wood\\Vision Government Solutions Inc V8.3.3\\Data Service",
            "",
            "path         : /Dataservice.V8.3.5",
            "PhysicalPath : C:\\Wood\\Vision Government Solutions Inc V8.3.5\\Data Service",
            "",
            "path         : /CamaAPI.V8.3.5",
            "PhysicalPath : C:\\Wood\\Vision Government Solutions Inc V8.3.5\\CAMA API",
            "",
            "path         : /AppServerManager.V8.3.5",
            "PhysicalPath : C:\\Wood\\Vision Government Solutions Inc V8.3.5\\AppServer Manager",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            ""
        ]
```

I would like to deserialize this into maybe a structured dictionary so that I can parse it.

Ultimately what I am trying to do is use the win_iis_webapplication module to remove the web application (it requires the name). I have no way of knowing what the name might be but I do know for certain the physical path. So, I want to get the name (Path: /QAWOOD8.3.3.Dataservice) based on searching the physical path (PhysicalPath: C:\Wood\Vision Government Solutions Inc V8.3.3\Data Service.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have now. Which throws an error because I dont understand what I am doing.

I put in the literal path for testing, but ultimately the physical path will be a variable (dataservice_dir.files[0].path)

```
  - name: Create structured dictionary for Data Service
      set_fact:
        data_service_info: "{{ web_apps_output.stdout_lines | join(' ') | json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        query: "[?contains(@, 'PhysicalPath : C:\\\\Wood\\\\Vision Government Solutions Inc V8.3.5\\\\Data Service')]"
      when: "'C:\\Wood\\Vision Government Solutions Inc V8.3.5\\Data Service' in web_apps_output.stdout_lines"
```

This also threw errors

```
- name: Create structured dictionary for Data Service
  set_fact:
    data_service_info:
      path: "{{ web_apps_output.stdout_lines | select('match', 'path         : /Dataservice.V8.3.5' | regex_escape) | first }}"
      PhysicalPath: "{{ web_apps_output.stdout_lines | select('match', 'PhysicalPath : C:\\Wood\\Vision Government Solutions Inc V8.3.5\\Data Service' | regex_escape) | first }}"
  when: 'C:\\Wood\\Vision Government Solutions Inc V8.3.5\\Data Service' in web_apps_output.stdout_lines
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This is useful to know if you are new to Ansible, like I am, and you are working with Windows servers.

What you want to do is format your PowerShell outputs to JSON by piping it to the `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet.

So the same output I posted above now looks like this:

```json
[
    {
        "path":  "/QAWOOD8.3.3.API",
        "PhysicalPath":  "C:\\Wood\\Vision Government Solutions Inc V8.3.3\\CAMA API"
    },
    {
        "path":  "/QAWOOD8.3.3.AppServerManager",
        "PhysicalPath":  "C:\\Wood\\Vision Government Solutions Inc V8.3.3\\AppServer Manager"
    },
    {
        "path":  "/CamaAPI.V8.3.5",
        "PhysicalPath":  "C:\\Wood\\Vision Government Solutions Inc V8.3.5\\CAMA API"
    },
    {
        "path":  "/AppServerManager.V8.3.5",
        "PhysicalPath":  "C:\\Wood\\Vision Government Solutions Inc V8.3.5\\AppServer Manager"
    }
]
```

This makes it a compatible format for Ansible’s `from_json` filter to create a dictionary out of it, like so:

```
set_fact:
    web_applications: "{{ web_apps_output.stdout | from_json }}"
```

From there, I can now query what I want using the keys:

```yaml
- name: Find web application with specific PhysicalPath
  set_fact:
    data_service_info: "{{ web_applications | selectattr('PhysicalPath', 'equalto', 'C:\\Wood\\Vision Government Solutions Inc V8.3.3\\Data Service') | first }}"
  when: "'C:\\Wood\\Vision Government Solutions Inc V8.3.3\\Data Service' in web_applications | map(attribute='PhysicalPath') | list"
```

And I can use `.notation`—the `[1:]` is to trim off the forward slash so that I have just the web application name:

```yaml
- name: Extracting web application name
  set_fact:
    data_service_name: "{{ data_service_info.path[1:] }}"
```